# How can I format a date time with millisecond precision AND left padding?

Tags: .net, datetime, string-formatting

For an API call, I need to represent a DateTime as a string including the milliseconds, but in a format that doesn't seem to be supported by `DateTime.ToString`.

Specifically, I need to capture the date including 3 decimal digits of the milliseconds (that is, milliseconds but no microseconds) and send that left padded with zeroes to 4 place. So if the actual milliseconds are `123`, I need to send `0123`. (I am aware that milliseconds are always <1000 and so one would never need 4 places, but I didn't design and have no control over this API.)

I wanted to do the simple thing and use a format like `yyyyMMddHHmmssffff`, but it seems that this shows milliseconds to 4 digits of precision, not three digits with left padding.

I know that I could separate the date into second and sub-second resolution, format them separately, and concatenate, but this seems klunky.

Is there a built-in format string that does what I need?

Comment: can't you do something like `yyyyMMddHHmmss0fff`? since it's alway a 0

Comment: Hey, that's genius! So simple and it works! Post as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @JoshuaFrank - Don't perpetuate madness under the guise of "I was just following orders".  It's all of our jobs to push back on these sort of things.  If they want four decimals, you should *right* pad it. `1230`, not `0123`.

Comment: @MattJohnson: I want you to know that I agree with you and I'll try it, but it might not work and yet my job requires that I make it work. These people may be technically misguided, but they're not murdering people, so I'm not sure how much moral outrage I want to summon to fight them.

Comment: @MattJohnson: By "might not work", I mean that this is one of those fiddly OAuth scenarios where every byte is significant, and changing the format of what they're expecting could well blow things up. It's already happened to me on this project and right now I just need to be done with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want the 0 to be always 0 no matter what, no need to make it dynamic, you can simply add it as a char:

```
yyyyMMddHHmmss0fff
```

Answer (score 2):

Since that's a highly-misleading and user-error-prone way to represent a date, given that "0123" would be interpreted as 12.3 milliseconds, I would say no, there's no way to do that except the "klunky" way you mentioned.

Comment: Thanks. There are many, many thing about this API that are awful, but I suppose this contributes a little bit extra.